# Cannot instantiate test steps class

Tags: java, selenium, cucumber

I have following jar files added to my project :

1. gherkin 2.12
2. cucumber-junit 1.2.5
3. cucumber-java 1.2.5
4. cucumber core 1.2.5
5. cucumber jvm-deps 1.0.5
6. cobetura 2.1.1
7. mockito all 1.9.1
8. cucumber-reporting 3.13

I am getting an error when I try to run test runner class:

```
 cucumber.runtime.CucumberException: Failed to instantiate class stepDefinition.Test_steps
```

**Test Runner Class**:

```
package CucumberTest;

import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber;
import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions;

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(
        features = "Feature"
        ,glue={"stepDefinition"}
        )

public class TestRunner {


}
```

**Test_steps Class**

```
package stepDefinition;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;
import PageObject.LoginVariables;
import cucumber.api.PendingException;
import cucumber.api.java.en.Given;
import cucumber.api.java.en.Then;
import cucumber.api.java.en.When;


public class Test_steps {

    private static WebDriver driver = null;
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 60);

    @Given("^User is on Homepage$")
    public void user_is_on_Homepage() throws Throwable {
        // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Selenium\\chromedriver.exe");
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.get("http://test.salesforce.com");

        throw new PendingException();
    }

    @When("^User Enters userId and Password$")
    public void user_Enters_userId_and_Password() throws Throwable {
        // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions

        wait.until(ExpectedConditions
                .visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath(LoginVariables.login_xpath)))
                .sendKeys("username@mail.com");

        wait.until(ExpectedConditions
                .visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath(LoginVariables.password_xpath)))
                .sendKeys("password");

        wait.until(ExpectedConditions
                .visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath(LoginVariables.login_xpath))).click();

        throw new PendingException();
    }

    @Then("^User is able to login sucessfully in salesorce$")
    public void user_is_able_to_login_sucessfully_in_salesorce() throws Throwable {
        // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions

        System.out.println("User Login Sucessful");
        throw new PendingException();
    }

}
```

Folder Structure:
[image: Folder Structure]

Comment: Please don't vandalize your own question.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is on the second line of the code below since the "driver" object is null when the "wait" is initialized and that causes a NullPointerException.

```
private static WebDriver driver = null;
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 60);
```

You should initialize the "driver" on a Before hook or initialize the "wait" after the "driver" has been initialized.

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me like your folder structure is wrong, I'd place the TestRunner at the top of my test packages rather than the src package. The pageobjects and stepdefs also belong in the test packages rather than src and the feature files belong in the test resources folder.

Answer (score 0):

At the first look @AndréBarbosa 's Answer looked pretty promising to me. However you need to take care of all these aspects mentioned below :

- As you are trying to cast the `WebDriver` instance to `WebDriverWait` when the driver is **null** as below, this should have given you a **NullPointerException** at **Runtime**. But seems we are not reaching here even.

  ```
  private static WebDriver driver = null;
  WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 60);
  ```
- As you have used `WebDriverWait` you should remove the `ImplicitlyWait` totally as [**`documentation`**](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp#explicit-and-implicit-waits) clearly says:

  ```
  WARNING: Do not mix implicit and explicit waits. Doing so can cause unpredictable wait times. For example setting an implicit wait of 10 seconds and an explicit wait of 15 seconds, could cause a timeout to occur after 20 seconds.
  ```
- Ideally, each and every element (except the `JavaScript` / `AJAX Call`) won't take 60 seconds to be visible/clickable/interactable. Hence you can be dynamic as follows :

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("element_xpath"))).sendKeys("value");
  ```
- The **`Feature Folder`** looks to me as the main concern. The **`Feature`** folder and **`LogIn.feature`** file looks unused. This may happen if you have moved or copied the **`Feature`** folder from another project. Hence the solution will be to **delete** the **`Feature`** folder totally and create a new **`Feature`** folder and **`LogIn.feature`** file  through your **`IDE`** only (not through other softwares `Notepad` or `Textpad` or `SubLime3`) as per the image below (`New` -> `File`) :

[image: New_Feature_File_Folder]

- Clean up you **`Project Workspace`** within your **`IDE`** and execute the `Test`
- Run **`CCleaner`** tool before and after `Test Execution` to wipe away all the OS chores.

> **Note** : Do not `move`/`copy` feature `file(s)`/`directory(ies)`. **Delete** the `unwanted` and create a **new** one through your **`IDE`** only.

Comment: Cucumber will automatically scan the folder mentioned in the "features" option of the runner for feature files, which avoids the need to specifically mention feature file names. Though it is more appropriate to store feature files inside the test\resource hierarchy.

Comment: @Grasshopper For the time being I will restrain myself from commenting on if **it is more appropriate to store feature files inside the test\resource hierarchy** but my framework executes **perfecto** keeping the `Feature` folder just below the `Project Workspace` hierarchy.

Comment: @kapil Did you get a chance to look into this Answer? Let us know the status.