# Old feature file path is used even after updating a new path

Tags: eclipse, selenium, cucumber, bdd, cucumber-jvm

I am new to cucumber and I am automating a scenario. Initially I kept my features files in the path C:\Users\test\eclipse-workspace\Automation\src\test\resources\featureFile. Then I moved the feature files to a different path (C:\Users\test\eclipse-workspace\Automation\src\test\com\test]automation\features). I have updated the same in CucumberOptions as shown below.

```
@CucumberOptions(features = {
        "src/test/java/com/test/automation/features/CO_Self_Service_Home_Page_Personalizations.feature" }, glue = {
                "src/test/java/com/oracle/peoplesoft/HCM/StepDefinitions" })
```

But when I try to run the feature, I am getting the below exception stating the feature file is not found. Here the path shown in the exception is the old path. I am not sure from where it is fetched as I have updated the new path in Cucumber options. Can you please help me understand the cause of this issue.

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a
>   file or directory:
>   C:\Users\test\eclipse-workspace\Automation\src\test\resources\featureFile\Self_Service_Home_Page_Personalizations.feature
>     at
>   cucumber.runtime.io.FileResourceIterator$FileIterator.(FileResourceIterator.java:54)
>     at
>   cucumber.runtime.io.FileResourceIterator.(FileResourceIterator.java:20)
>     at
>   cucumber.runtime.io.FileResourceIterable.iterator(FileResourceIterable.java:19)
>     at
>   cucumber.runtime.model.CucumberFeature.loadFromFeaturePath(CucumberFeature.java:103)
>     at
>   cucumber.runtime.model.CucumberFeature.load(CucumberFeature.java:54)
>     at
>   cucumber.runtime.model.CucumberFeature.load(CucumberFeature.java:34)
>     at
>   cucumber.runtime.RuntimeOptions.cucumberFeatures(RuntimeOptions.java:235)
>     at cucumber.runtime.Runtime.run(Runtime.java:110)   at
>   cucumber.api.cli.Main.run(Main.java:36)   at
>   cucumber.api.cli.Main.main(Main.java:18)

Comment: There is an extra 'java' in the value set to features. The 'java' part is missing  in the part where you mention the new folder hierarchy.

Comment: See the last point - Possible duplicate of [Cannot instantiate test steps class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47925875/cannot-instantiate-test-steps-class/47927644#47927644)

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of points you need to take care as follows :

- As per `Best Practices` cerate the directory **`features`** which will contain the **`featurefile(s)`** strictly through your **`IDE`** only (not through other softwares `Notepad` or `Textpad` or `SubLime3`) as per the image below (`New` -> `File`) :

[image: CO_Self_Service_Home_Page_Personalizations]

- Create the `featurefile` i.e. **`CO_Self_Service_Home_Page_Personalizations.feature`** within **`features`** directory strictly through your **`IDE`** only.
- Keep your **`Project Structure`** simple by placing the directory containing the featurefile(s) just under  **`Project Workspace`**. For `Featurefiles` Cucumber works with directory names. So create the **features** directory just under your project space **Automation** (same hierarchy as **src**). So the location of the **`Self_Service_Home_Page_Personalizations.feature`** will be :

  ```
  C:\Users\test\eclipse-workspace\Automation\features\Self_Service_Home_Page_Personalizations.feature
  ```
- Again, as in your `Class` file containing **`@CucumberOptions`** you have mentioned  **`glue = {"StepDefinitions" }`** ensure that the `Class` file containing **`@CucumberOptions`** must be in the similar hierarchy as the figure below :

[image: Cucumber_Project_Structure]

- So your **`CucumberOptions`** will be as follows :

  ```
  @CucumberOptions(features = {"features" }, glue = {"StepDefinitions" })
  ```
- Execute your **`Test`**

> **Note** : Do not `move`/`copy` feature `file(s)`/`directory(ies)`. **Delete** the unwanted and `create` a **new** one through your **IDE** only.